# Fastlane Android: upload_to_play_store with track set to internal uploads screenshots to production?

Tags: android, fastlane

I am developing a CI/CD pipeline for an android app. I use this line to upload the app:

```
upload_to_play_store(track:'internal', aab: binarypath, skip_upload_changelogs: true, metadata_path: metadatapath, package_name: appId)
```

Now it seems the screenshots uploaded for the test track also appear to me when I am not part of the test track?
Is this intentional? It seems like quite dangerous behavior?

I would have expected that no data is published to real users if I set track: internal?
Or is some sort of caching playing a trick on me?

EDIT: Nope, I verified this with an external person, the screenshots of the in-development app really were published. Seems like internal tracks do not have their own screenshots.
I'd be happy if anybody can confirm this is intentional behavior of fastlane/google.